# Where is the associated token account in Metaplex .create() output?

Tags: nft, associated-token-account, metaplex-js

From https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#create:

> This will take care of creating the mint account, the associated token account, the metadata PDA and the original edition PDA (a.k.a. the master edition) for you.

```
const createOutput = await metaplex
    .nfts()
    .create({
        uri: "https://arweave.net/123",
        name: "My NFT",
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: 500, // Represents 5.00%.
    })
    .run();
```

**Where is the associated token account in the `.create().run()` output?**

Answer (score 1):

**Answering my own question to help others.**

Using SolScan to look at the associated token address created after minting a token, you can see the associated token account in the

```
"tokenAddress": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
```

part of the `.create().run()` output.

Comment: To add, this output structure is documented here: https://metaplex-foundation.github.io/js/types/js.CreateNftOutput.html